# src/main/resources file overwritten by src/test/resources

Tags: java, web-services, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I implemented a web service using spring-boot. It reads from a file during initialization. So I created the file as `src/main/resources/files/init_file.txt`. This is a huge file and it takes a moment to read during initialization. Anyway, the web service was able to read from the file and work as expected.

Then I added unit tests. Since this file was huge, I used a light-weight dummy file which I created as `src/test/resources/files/init_file.txt`. Note that this dummy file is in src/**test**/resources, and not in src/**main**/resources.

Unit tests worked as expected. However, now when I run the service (`mvn exec:java`), the service always reads the dummy file from test resources.

How can I ensure that the web service reads the correct file?

Excerpt from `pom.xml`:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>myproj-main</artifactId>
<name>myproj : Main</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>



<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>version.properties</exclude>
      <exclude>conf/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>version.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>

  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/config</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>static.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>

  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/config/local</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>application.properties</include>
      <include>secure.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>

  <resource>
    <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <!-- Springboot boot for maven -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <layout>ZIP</layout>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
      <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!--
       <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
          <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                      <destFile>${jacoco.out.path}${jacoco.out.file}</destFile>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>PRE-TEST-PARENT</id>
        <goals>
                              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
  -->
  <!-- Copy application configurations to test resources for tests. -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <!-- Include environment-invariant content from src/main/config -->
            <copy overwrite="true" todir="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" verbose="true">
              <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/config" includes="*">
                <type type="file"/>
                <!-- don't include subfolders -->
              </fileset>
            </copy>

            <!-- Include environment-variant content from src/main/config/${test.config.profile}, including subfolders -->
            <copy overwrite="true" todir="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" verbose="true">
              <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/config/${test.config.profile}" includes="**/*"/>
            </copy>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I also tried using `<excludes>` to exclude `src/test/resources/*` but it did not work.

```
nik@ubuntu:myproj-main$ mvn exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproj : Main 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ myproj-main >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce) @ myproj-main ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ myproj-main <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ myproj-main ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.2.RELEASE)

2015-01-23 13:05:43,101  INFO [com.mycom.comnt.Application] Starting Application on ubuntu with PID 63446 (/home/nik/work/myproj/myproj-main/target/classes started by nik in /home/nik/work/myproj/myproj-main)
2015-01-23 13:05:43,101 DEBUG [com.mycom.comnt.Application] Running with Spring Boot v1.0.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.0.5.RELEASE
2015-01-23 13:05:48,311  INFO [com.mycom.comnt.Application] ServletContext initialized
2015-01-23 13:05:48,496  INFO [com.mycom.comnt.services.EventStatusService] Event availability service: found 3 available events
2015-01-23 13:05:51,822  INFO [com.mycom.comnt.Application] Started Application in 8.896 seconds (JVM running for 11.973)
```

Comment: Nik. This is bizzare, can you post a little bit more of your pom.xml? When you use `mvn clean package` which version ends inside the jar?

Comment: Also post your command line to `mvn exec:java`, maybe it is including `-Dexec.classpathScope="test"` or something.

Comment: The generated `war` packs the correct file.

Comment: Can you execute that command with the -X option to turn on debug logging and share the result somehow?

Comment: I also noticed the following config in pom:

<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.mycom.comnt.TestMain</mainClass>
          <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Does that look okay? the classpathScope is `test`

Answer (score 1):

Exec let you specify the [classpath scope](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-or-java-change-classpath-scope.html).

It can be set to `compile`,`test`, `runtime` or `system` (default is `runtime`).

OP set it to test:

```
<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
```

Either remove it or specify the classpath scope from the command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="runtime"
```